# Lua Alien - Defined variables in the Win32 API WaitForSingleObject function

Tags: winapi, lua, lua-alien

I am using [Alien for Lua](http://alien.luaforge.net/) to reference the [WaitForSingleObject function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the Windows Kernel32.dll.

I am pretty new to Windows programming, so the question I have is about the following [#define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yt3yck0x.aspx)d variables referenced by the WaitForSingleObject documentation:

> If dwMilliseconds is **INFINITE**, the function will return only when the object is signaled.

What is the **INFINITE** value?  I would naturally assume it to be `-1`, but I cannot find this to be documented anywhere.

Also, with the following table, it mentions the return values in hexadecimal, but I am confused as to why they have an `L` character after the last digit.  Could this be something as simple as casting it to a Long?

[image: Chart]

The reason I ask is because Lua uses a [Number data type](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.3.html), so I am not sure if I should be checking for this return value via Hex digits (0-F) or decimal digits (0-9)?

Comment: the `L` at the end is the literal syntax for a `long`. see [this link](http://cpp.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html) for a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thought crossed my mind to just open a C++ application and print out these values, so I did just that:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << INFINITE;
    std::cout << WAIT_OBJECT_0;
    std::cout << WAIT_ABANDONED;
    std::cout << WAIT_TIMEOUT;
    std::cout << WAIT_FAILED;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The final Lua results based off my findings is:

```
local INFINITE = 4294967295
local WAIT_OBJECT_0 = 0
local WAIT_ABANDONED = 128
local WAIT_TIMEOUT = 258
local WAIT_FAILED = 4294967295
```

Comment: `INFINTIE` uses an unsigned integer type. `4294967295` is the same as `-1` when interpreted as a signed integer type instead.

Comment: Good to note!  Thanks!

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just noticed that `INFINTIE` has a typo.  I think it should be: `INFINITE`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to Google for the same information.  Eventually, I found this Q&A.

I found two sources with: `#define INFINITE 0xFFFFFFFF`

- https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/um/WinBase.h#L704
- https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-tools/widl/include/winbase.h#L365

For function `WaitForSingleObject`, parameter `dwMilliseconds` has type `DWORD`.

From here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

I can see: `DWORD   A 32-bit unsigned integer.`

Thus, `@RemyLebeau`'s comment above looks reasonable & valid:

```
`4294967295` is the same as `-1` when interpreted as a signed integer type instead.`
```

In short: `((DWORD) -1) == INFINITE`

Last comment: Ironically, this "infinite" feels similar to the Boeing 787 problem where they needed to reboot/restart the plane once per 51 days.  Feels eerily close / similar!